# Customizable text alignment for the personal statement on Developer Story

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

The personal statement seems hardcoded to be center-aligned. It looks ugly to me. It would be nice to allow HTML blocks like:

```
<div style="text-align: justify"> 
    text...
</div>
```

Comment: Or, if it looks better justified, just make it justified for everyone. I know, I know, we're developers, so we love knobs and switches...

Comment: We'll update the design (and alignment) of the personal statement to be left aligned. That said, I don't think we'll allow customizable text-alignment.

Comment: @Stéphane status update on this?

Comment: Any new @Stéphane? It seems like 2 years from your last comment. Thanks.